# JavaScript run a function multiple times every 4 sec

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I have been working on a piece of code and I was wondering if there is a inbuilt JavaScript method which allows a function to be runned every 4 seconds for seconds and 5 times for example.

Comment: Why not use setInterval??

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous in the sense that it is unclear whether you want to call the function five times *each* interval, or call it with intervals *until it has been called five times*.

## 5 times *each* time interval

You can easily write a higher order function for this:

```
function multi_repeat(f,dmsec,times) {
    function foo() {
        setTimeout(foo,dmsec);
        for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            f();
        }
    }
    setTimeout(foo,dmsec);
}
```

Now if your function is:

```
function the_alert() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

You can run this with:

```
multi_repeat(the_alert,4000,5);
```

where `4000` is the number of milliseconds (so `4` seconds is `4000` milliseconds) and `5` the number of times the function should be called.

## *Stop* after 5 calls

In case the procedure should stop after 5 calls, you can define another higher order function:

```
function repeat_stop(f,dmsec,times) {
    var count = 0;
    function foo() {
        f();
        count++;
        if(count < times) {
            setTimeout(foo,dmsec);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(foo,dmsec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at the setInverval function.

```
var counter = 0;
function someFunction(){
    console.log('hello world')
}

var interVal = setInterval(function(){ 
  conter++;
  if (counter < 5) {
      someFunction();
  }
  else {
      clearInterval(interVal );
  }
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you update the `counter`? Right now it will never reach `5`.

Answer (score -1):

`setInterval` will run a function repeatedly with a custom delay between them. To run it five times, you'll have to handle that yourself, e.g.

```
setInterval(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    myFunction();
  }
},4000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: you are not Clearing the interval the function keeps on executing.. and wasting cpu time...every 4 seconds

Comment: @AdrianBratu: the question is ambigu to the point whether it should be called 5 times each time, or stop after 5 intervals.

Comment: As per the question: "a function to be runned every 4 seconds"